# Error on appendChild - An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any reason why this isn't working? Seems simple enough. I get this error in the console. I'm trying to populate the unordered list using the values from the array.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="intro.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="main">
                <ul id="menu"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var menuItems = ["Home","About","Contact Us", "Sign in"];

$(document).ready(function (){
    console.log("Populating menu");
    var elem = document.getElementById('menu');

    for(var i=0;i<menuItems.length;i++){

        elem.appendChild("<li id='" + menuItems[i] + "'>" + menuItems[i] + "</li>" );       
    }
    console.log('menu populated.');
});
```

Comment: What is `container` used for? Why is it selected outside of `ready`?

Comment: NO reason. Just thought I'd use it at some point so I grabbed it.

Comment: *What* does not work? Please state your problem explicitly. Is your question title some kind of error message? If so, where did it happpen?

Comment: Trying to populate UL using what's in the array on load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick with jQuery, `appendChild` doesn't accept strings, only nodes

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var container = $("#container"),
        elem      = $('#menu'),
        menuItems = ["Home", "About", "Contact Us", "Sign in"];

    $.each(menuItems, function(idx, item) {
        $('<li />', {
            id   : item.replace(/\s+/,'_'), // no spaces here
            text : item
        }).appendTo(elem);
    });
});
```

Comment: I've seen this format before, could you explain what's going on here or does this type of function have a name I could look up. For example, whats the "idx" for?

Comment: idx is just a short version of index, it's the index of the loop. It's all in the documentation -> [element creation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements) | [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: What's happening with the regex? Couldn't I do something like menuItems[idx]?

Comment: @Batman - You're using the array values as ID's for your elements, and ID's can't have spaces, and you can't have two ID's, so I replaced any space with an underscore to make the ID valid, that's what the regex is for. Optimally, you should add toLowerCase() to make the ID's the lower case as well, as that would make it easier to target them, but uppercase isn't really invalid, so I didn't add that.

Comment: I just realized that item is equivalent to menuItems[idx]. Makes sense now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to stick to 100% JavaScript, use `document.createElement("li")`

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exLvP/)

```
var ul = document.getElementById("myID")
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("id", "myLI" + i);
    li.innerText = "Hello " + i
    ul.appendChild(li)
}
```

Comment: Why use `li.setAttribute("id", "myLI" + i);` when `li.id = "myLI" + i;` is more direct?

Comment: innerText is not cross browser

Comment: yep... use standard `textContent` (ie9+), or create a new text node, or just use innerHTML.

Comment: I probably should have just used document.createTextNode("Hello"). Best to stick with a unified approach for readability